# Pykalman with non-square observation matrix

Tags: python, matrix, kalman-filter, pykalman

In the documentation of `Pykalman` it says that it only accepts square matrices for the `observation_matrices` and `transition_matrices` arguments.

Is there a way around this? I have to estimate a state-space system with a non-square observation matrix. Using the `Pykalman` notation, its dimensions would be `[n_dim_obs, n_dim_state]`.

I could not find any other kalman filter library that accepts non-square observation matrices **and** has a loglikelihood method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some experience with Pykalman and its documentation seems to have a lot of mistakes. So the observation matrix does not have to be a square one. It just has to map the estimation state to the measurement matrix.

[image: formula]

Please have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47210512/using-pykalman-on-raw-acceleration-data-to-calculate-position). The observation matrix looks like H = [0 0 1] and Pykalman works fine. The dimension is exactly how you expect it: [n_dim_obs, n_dim_state].

If you need additinal information I would be glad to help.

Comment: Great! I will have a look at it. I'll let you know if I run into any problems. Thank you for the attention.